# How to read input in UTF-8 in c# using Console.readLine?

Tags: c#

I want to take the input in UTF-8 character encoded using `Console.ReadLine()` or any other method in C#. In java I have found this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");
```

I'm getting this output: `I0NISMS4QhiSWnSIADCAXg`

But the expected output is this type: `{"result": 5, "id": 1}`

Comment: Perhaps try [Console.InputEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.inputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Tried but not worked

Comment: That is a base64 encoded string, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the console or utf8.  The binary data encoded in that string does not have a recognizable match with the json style output you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the `Console.OutputEncoding` to `UTF-8`:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

for example :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test1.txt",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**AND** also configure your console font such this:

[image]

Comment: i don't wan't to read input from file i'want to take it from user